# What should I be afraid of when I make a site public?

Tags: sql-injection

If I was going to put my site for the public's use, what are some security issues that I should be worried about?

I know of SQL injections. 
What other hacks/injections should I be aware of?

Comment: clowns. always clowns. and maybe unicorns.

Comment: @SkySanders. +1 That is awesome advice. It's also not well known, but thanks for making us all aware of the various threats that exist :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends heavily on what kind of site you're putting up. Sites that deal with commerce and payment systems need to be more secure then a site detailing how to wash your cat.

In essence the more personal user interaction a site has, the more it's going to need to be checked for security vulnerabilities. A static html site will probably not have many issues while a site that allows people to register, purchase items, pay with a credit card online, etc, is going to need a much closer look at things under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

[Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

[Cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

Comment: Yes, I meant to mention that. Thanks!